# Why is there Failed Auth error when connecting fastify server to second mongoDB cluster?

Tags: mongodb, server, fastify

I'm trying to add a database connection to a fastify server, for various reasons, this is the scenario, and there are two separate mongodb's that must be connected to.

index.js:

```
'use strict'

const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

const path = require('path');
const tunnel = require('tunnel-ssh');
const Autoload = require('fastify-autoload');
const fastifyMongoose = require('fastify-mongoose-driver');
const fastify = require('fastify');
const { runTasks } = require('./taskRunner.js')
const { connectPerformanceDB } = require('./performanceDB.js')

const fastifyServer = fastify({ logger: process.env.DEVELOPMENT });

const User = require('./schemas/User');
const Promo = require('./schemas/Promo');
const Result = require('./schemas/PageSpeedResult')

fastifyServer.register(Autoload, { dir: path.join(__dirname, 'routes') });

const tunnelConfig = {
  username: '*****',
  host: '*****.com',
  privateKey: require('fs').readFileSync('../../.ssh/id_rsa'),
  srcPort: 27017,
  dstPort: 27017
};

tunnel(tunnelConfig, error => {

  if (error) console.log('SSH connection error: ', + error);

  fastifyServer.register(fastifyMongoose, {
    uri: process.env.MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING,
    settings: {
      user: '*************',
      pass: '*************',
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      config: {
        autoIndex: true
      }
    },
    models: [User, Promo],
    useNameAndAlias: true
  });

  fastifyServer.register(fastifyMongoose, {
    uri: process.env.PERFORMANCE_DB_CONNECTION_STRING, 
    settings: {
      user: '******',
      pass: '**********',
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      config: {
        autoIndex: true
      }
    },
    models: [Result],
    useNameAndAlias: true
  })

  fastifyServer.listen(process.env.PORT, (err, address) => {

    if (err) throw err;

    fastifyServer.log.info(`server listening on ${address}`);
  });
});
```

The issue im running into is that this current code errors out like so:

```
index.js:102
    if (err) throw err;
             ^

MongoError: Authentication failed.
```

the line it errors on is the if statement inside this block:

```
fastifyServer.listen(process.env.PORT, (err, address) => {
    
   if (err) throw err;
    
   fastifyServer.log.info(`server listening on ${address}`);
});
```

Confirmed user, pass, and database are correct.

the connect uri const looks like: `mongodb://localhost/<name_of_cluster>`, have also tried the connect string given in mongo's web application under the connect tab.

Any suggestions on the failed auth error or implementing a second DB cluster with fastify?

UPDATE:
ive tried multiple connection strings. both the one mentioned in the post, as well as `mongodb://<username>:<pass>@pagespeedinsights-hjdvp.mongodb.net/<database>?retryWrites=true&w=majority` and `mongodb+srv://<username>:<pass>@pagespeedinsights-hjdvp.mongodb.net/<database>?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

the first errors in the server with:

`Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND pagespeedinsights-hjdvp.mongodb.net`

the second errors (from same line as initial line above) in server with:

```
index.js:102
    if (err) throw err;
             ^

TypeError: schema[key].forEach is not a function
```

Comment: Look in the server error log.

Comment: @D.SM the error mentioned is from the server error log

Comment: since the logs tell `MongoError: Authentication failed.` did you try to set the auth in the uri? `mongodb://user:password@localhost/dbName`

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon ive tried multiple connection strings. both the one mentioned in the post, as well as `mongodb://<username>:<pass>@pagespeedinsights-hjdvp.mongodb.net/<database>?retryWrites=true&w=majority` and `mongodb+srv://<username>:<pass>@pagespeedinsights-hjdvp.mongodb.net/<database>?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

Comment: Could you try to register only one `fastifyMongoose`? I suspect the plugin doesn't support multiple registrations.

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon yes only one resgistered db cluster works. but i need two

Comment: Ok, I got the problem. Do your handlers need to use both Mongo or some routes need the first one, and other routes need the second one?

Comment: we scrapped the use of mongoose fastify, thanks any way @ManuelSpigolon

Answer (score 0):

The problem depends on the plugin `require('fastify-mongoose-driver')` since this line is executed every time you will register this plugin:

```
await mongoose.connect(uri, settings);
```

[Here the source code](https://github.com/alex-ppg/fastify-mongoose/blob/3ca860ae03eaf4191ab70c2b4763492c85cfbadc/index.js#L59)

So, that plugin uses a singleton as the connection for every registration overriding the first ones.

This is what happens under the hood:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

// docker run -d -p 27018:27017 --rm -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=adminOne -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password --name mongoOne mongo:4
// docker run -d -p 27019:27017 --rm -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=adminTwo -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password --name mongoTwo mongo:4

;(async function () {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://adminOne:password@localhost:27018')
  console.log('connected 1')

  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://adminTwo:password@localhost:27019')
  console.log('connected 2')

  const kittySchema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: String })
  const Kitten = mongoose.model('Kitten', kittySchema)

  // it will be saved on second connection

  const silence = new Kitten({ name: 'Silence' })
  silence.save(function (err, fluffy) {
    if (err) return console.error(err)
    console.log(fluffy)
  })
})()
```

And this recreates the same error you have:

```
const fastify = require('fastify')()

fastify.register(require('fastify-mongoose-driver').plugin,
  {
    uri: 'mongodb://adminOne:password@localhost:27018',
    settings: {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      config: { autoIndex: true }
    },
    models: [{ name: 'Kittens', schema: { name: String } }]
  }
)

fastify.register(require('fastify-mongoose-driver').plugin,
  {
    uri: 'mongodb://adminTwo:password@localhost:27019',
    settings: {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      config: { autoIndex: true }
    },
    models: [{ name: 'Dogs', schema: { name: String } }]
  }
)

fastify.ready(err => {
  console.log(err) // TypeError: schema[key].forEach is not a function
})
```

You should use the [mongoose multiple connections](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#multiple_connections) configurations to archive your needs and implement/or wait and upgrade of that plugin to support this feature.